# How do I set a background view's size equal to a foreground view's size?

Tags: swiftui

I have a foreground view and a background view. The foreground view contains some text, images, and a couple of stack views. It automatically sizes itself and looks perfect. I want to add a background view that matches the automatic size of my foreground view. My background view is a `View` composed of some shapes.

Things I've tried:

- If I use a `ZStack`, my background view sizes itself (filling the container).
- If I overlay the background on top of the foreground, the background view has the correct size but it obscures the foreground view.
- If I overlay the foreground view on top of the background view, the background view determines it's own size.

### Code Sample

#### Foreground View

```
struct ForegroundView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: "photo")
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Title")
                Text("Subtitle")
            }
            Spacer()
            Text("42")
        }
    }
    
}

struct ForegroundView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

#### Background View

The background view is a progress bar.

```
struct ProgressBar: View {
    @Binding var value: Float
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { gr in
            ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(width: gr.size.width,
                           height: gr.size.height)
                    .opacity(0.3)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemTeal))
                
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(width: min(CGFloat(self.value)*gr.size.width, gr.size.width),
                           height: gr.size.height)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemBlue))
                    .animation(.linear)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ProgressBar_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ProgressBar(value: .constant(0.5))
    }
}
```

#### Things I Tried

```
struct Demo_Preview: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            // Attempt 1
            ZStack {
                ProgressBar(value: .constant(0.5))
                ForegroundView()
            }

            // Attempt 2
            ForegroundView().overlay(ProgressBar(value: .constant(0.5)))

            // Attempt 3
            ProgressBar(value: .constant(0.5)).overlay(ForegroundView())
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer, it turns out, is quite simple: the [background modifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/background(_:alignment:)).

```
struct Demo_Preview: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            ForegroundView().background(ProgressBar(value: .constant(0.5)))
        }
    }
}
```